# Configuring .NET Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have created simple web service using C# by creating new site and adding new web service in Visual Studio. I have also created site for it in IIS8 and placed service there. Service works fine and returns XML as answer, but now I need to return JSON format or even better - both formats available in separate address . How to achieve that? Should I manage something with web.config file, or I must do some coding?

web.config file content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change response format of your web method by decorating it with `ScriptMethod` attribute, and return data with `JavaScriptSerializer`. [That](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4/) article has a complete example, I'll post it below:

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    [WebMethod]
    public Employee[] GetEmployessXML()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {
        new Employee()
        {
            Id=101,
            Name="Nitin",
            Salary=10000
        },
        new Employee()
        {
            Id=102,
            Name="Dinesh",
            Salary=100000
        }
        };
        return emps;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetEmployessJSON()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {
        new Employee()
        {
            Id=101,
            Name="Nitin",
            Salary=10000
        },
        new Employee()
        {
            Id=102,
            Name="Dinesh",
            Salary=100000
        }
        };
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(emps);
    }
}
```